# Connect ffmpeg and pyaudio by rtmp

Tags: python, ffmpeg, stream, rtmp, pyaudio

Is it possible in cross platform to create an rtmp connection with ffmpeg and pyaudio?

This the code:
Camera

```
import sys, pyaudio, subprocess, cv2
rtmp_url = "rtmp://MYURL"
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

fps = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS))
width = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
height = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))
```

Command ffmpeg

```
command = ['']
```

Init the microphone

```
CHUNK = 1024
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 1 if sys.platform == 'darwin' else 2
RATE = 44100
RECORD_SECONDS = 20
PyA = pyaudio.PyAudio()
stream = PyA.open(format=FORMAT, channels=CHANNELS, rate=RATE, input=True)
subProcess = subprocess.Popen(command, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Write the bytes

```
while stream.is_active():
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if not ret:
        print("frame read failed")
        break
    subProcess.stdin.write(frame.tobytes())

    subProcess.stdin.write(stream.read(CHUNK))
subProcess.stdin.close()
```

All in multiplatform.

Comment: It's not clear exactly what you're asking for. You wrote one sentence and pasted a bunch of code. Can you explain what you actually need help with? What exactly is missing here? What does this code do? What do you want it to do in the end that it's not doing? What are you having trouble with? It's not clear what you're stuck on. Your question is very broad and this code seems pretty specific. I suggest reading the [ask] page and the [tour] to get a better understanding of what kind of content is expected in questions on here.

Comment: command = ['ffmpeg -re -f rawvideo -vcodec rawvideo -pix_fmt bgr24 -s {}x{}".format(width, height) -r str(fps) -i - -f s16le -acodec pcm_s16le -r 44100 -ac 2 -i - -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -preset ultrafast -c:a aac -b 3000k -preset ultrafast -bufsize 64M -f flv rtmp_url']

Comment: Code does not go in comments. All code must go in the question itself.